# C++ Question about extraction operator return value

Tags: c++

> Many functions do not have an "extra" return value that they can use to indicate an error.
> For example, a function that reads an integer from input (such as `cin`'s operator `>>`) can obviously return
> any int value, so there is no int that it could return to indicate failure.

I'm a little confused because does this mean >> returns something? I thought a line liked this:
cin >> a;
Just means >> extracts what it can from the input stream and assigns it to the variable but it also returns something?

Comment: The point of the quoted sentence is true but the `std::cin` example is wrong since its `operator>>()` does not return the extracted value but the stream itself. The extracted value is stored in the given parameter (taken by reference).

Comment: Their overarching point is sometimes you'll see `int do_something(float x);` where the returned `int` may represent an error code. But other times for example `int add(int x, int y);` the return value would be the result of the computation, therefore you'd need a different error handling mechanism (exceptions, out params, returning tuples, etc)

Comment: I think your textbook (?) is written in a rather sloppy way. `istream& operator>> (int& val);` doesn't return an `int` but stores an integer value in its operand `val`. The return value is (per @Adrian Mare) something entirely different. However, the point that the author is trying to make is valid. Because every possible value of an `int` is valid, you cannot tell if the input operation failed just by looking at that value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `istream::operator>>(int&)` also return a value:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

> basic_istream& operator>>( int& value );

This is, it returns the `istream`, so it can be chained:

```
std::cin >> a >> b;
```

---

Back to the citation:

It seems to explain that a functions which is intended to return a result, because it returns that result can not at the same time return an error value.

This is kind of correct, at least before C++17 and it structured binding.

I suppose the book is about to explain exceptions.